# In google sheet how do I create sequence of string starting from 'aa', 'ab', .... 'ba'... 'zz'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for easy way to create  from
'aa', 'ab', .... 'ba'... 'zz'
each row should have one incremental value.
E.g. after 'aa' it should be 'ab'

After second char reaches 'z' it should be 'ba' and so on

Answer (score 1):

```
=CHAR(97 + INT((ROW(A1) - 1) / 26)) & CHAR(97 + MOD(ROW(A1) - 1, 26))
```

This formula should be placed in a cell and dragged down to fill as many cells as needed.

Using number 97 that becomes 'a', and then using mod from row number to add required number.

Answer (score 1):

`=arrayformula(tocol(char(sequence(26,1,65))&char(sequence(1,26,65))))`

Create the letters of the alphabet by feeding `char` with the output of `sequence` in a row and a column, `&` them to create a 2D array then flatten using `tocol`.

Also doable using `makearray`:
`=tocol(makearray(26,26,lambda(r,c,char(64+r)&char(64+c))))`